# How can i access: data-type = "mp4" from div?

Tags: css, xpath, tags, selector

I am trying to access the mp4 string inside the data-type attribute in python [image] using selenium.

Comment: post code, not pictures of code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can target the element that has that attribute with [`find_element_by_xpath()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_element_by_xpath-driver-method-selenium-python) and then use the [`get_attirbute()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_attribute-element-method-selenium-python/) method.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-type]").get_attribute("data-type")
```

Comment: let me try this one out.